# Could not authenticate with IBM Containers registry at registry.ng.bluemix.net

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

When I login to the IBM containers on Bluemix, I get the following error:

> cf ic login 
>   ** Retrieving client certificates from IBM Containers 
>   ** Storing client certificates in /Users/triplez/.ice/certs Successfully retrieved client certificates
>   ** Checking local docker configuration OK
>   ** Authenticating with registry at registry.ng.bluemix.net
>  
>   Could not authenticate with IBM Containers registry at registry.ng.bluemix.net
>   **** exit status 1
>   ****Error response from daemon: invalid registry endpoint registry.ng.bluemix.net/v0/: unable to ping registry endpoint
>   registry.ng.bluemix.net/v0/ 
>   v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get registry.ng.bluemix.net/v2/: dial tcp: lookup
>   registry.ng.bluemix.net on 103.11.48.126:53: read udp
>   103.11.48.126:53: i/o timeout  
>  
>   v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get registry.ng.bluemix.net/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup registry.ng.bluemix.net on 103.11.48.126:53: read udp
>   103.11.48.126:53: i/o timeout. If this private registry supports only  HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add
>   `--insecure-registry registry.ng.bluemix.net` to the daemon's
>   arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's
>   CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate
>   at /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.ng.bluemix.net/ca.crt

I've already uninstalled docker and reinstalled, giving me the same error. I've also deleted `~/.cf/config.json` and `~/.ice/ice-cfg.ini` and `~/.ice/certs/` and tried logging in again. I still receive the same error.

I've also tested this with ice cli with the same error.

EDITED

Tried this command:

```
ice login -a 'https://api.ng.bluemix.net' --registry 'registry.ng.bluemix.net' --host 'https://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net/v3/containers'
```

Got the same error:

> Authentication with container cloud service at
>   containers-api.ng.bluemix.net/v3/containers completed
>   successfully 
>   You can issue commands now to the container service
>
> Proceeding to authenticate with the container cloud registry at 
>   registry.ng.bluemix.net/v3 
>   Error response from daemon: invalid registry endpoint 
>   registry.ng.bluemix.net/v3/v0/: 
>   unable to ping registry endpoint registry.ng.bluemix.net/v3/v0/
>
> v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get registry.ng.bluemix.net/v3/v2/: 
>   dial tcp: lookup registry.ng.bluemix.net on 192.168.0.1:53: read ump 
>   192.168.0.1:53: i/o timeout
>   v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get registry.ng.bluemix.net/v3/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup registry.ng.bluemix.net on 192.168.0.1:53: read udp 192.168.0.1:53: i/o timeout. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry registry.ng.bluemix.net` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of
>   HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need
>   for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at
>   /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.ng.bluemix.net/ca.crt
>
> docker is not available on your system or is not properly configured
>
> Could not authenticate with cloud registry at registry.ng.bluemix.net/v3
>
> You can still use IBM Containers but will not be able to run local docker containers, push, or pull images

Comment: Can you try again? It looks like an intermittent issue with the service.

Comment: Just tried it. Same Error response.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the container cloud service host name is not correct.
Please try to run the ice login command as below:

```
ice login -a 'https://api.ng.bluemix.net' --registry 'registry.ng.bluemix.net' --host 'https://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net/v3/containers'
```

Comment: Could you please add the error output from the ice login command I suggested?

Comment: Authentication with container cloud service at https://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net/v3/containers completed successfully
You can issue commands now to the container service
 
Proceeding to authenticate with the container cloud registry at registry.ng.bluemix.net/v3
Error response from daemon: invalid registry endpoint https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/v3/v0/: unable to ping registry endpoint https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/v3/v0/

Comment: v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/v3/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry.ng.bluemix.net on 192.168.0.1:53: read udp 192.168.0.1:53: i/o timeout
 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/v3/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup registry.ng.bluemix.net on 192.168.0.1:53: read udp 192.168.0.1:53: i/o timeout. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry registry.ng.bluemix.net` to the daemon's arguments.

Comment: In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.ng.bluemix.net/ca.crt
docker is not available on your system or is not properly configured
Could not authenticate with cloud registry at registry.ng.bluemix.net/v3 
You can still use IBM Containers but will not be able to run local docker containers, push, or pull images

Comment: Your local docker instance is not configured properly. Please run $(boot2docker shellinit) to set docker environment variables. Then try a docker command like 'docker ps' to check if it is properly configured.

Comment: boot2docker has been deprecated. My docker is properly configured.

docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

I've been able to deploy containers locally.

Comment: Hello, could you run the following commands?
1- cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net
2- cf login (please be sure to use the right org and space)
3- cf ic login
4- cf ic info

Please paste any errors you get or (hopefully) the output of the last command

Comment: cf ic login
** Retrieving client certificates from IBM Containers
** Storing client certificates in /Users/triplez/.ice/certs
Successfully retrieved client certificates
** Checking local docker configuration
OK
** Authenticating with registry at registry.ng.bluemix.net
Could not authenticate with IBM Containers registry at registry.ng.bluemix.net
**** exit status 1
****Error response from daemon: invalid registry endpoint https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/v0/: unable to ping registry endpoint https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/v0/

Comment: v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry.ng.bluemix.net on 192.168.0.1:53: read udp 192.168.0.1:53: i/o timeout
 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup registry.ng.bluemix.net on 192.168.0.1:53: read udp 192.168.0.1:53: i/o timeout. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry registry.ng.bluemix.net` to the daemon's arguments.

Comment: In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.ng.bluemix.net/ca.crt

Comment: cf ic info
Date/Time                : 2015-09-10 00:27:52.415119022 +0800 SGT
Debug mode               : false
CCS host/url             : https://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net
Registry host            : registry.ng.bluemix.net
Bluemix api host/url     : https://api.ng.bluemix.net
Bluemix Org              : justinlee(1b0c5263-cb88-410f-b42d-e73f2143af18)
Bluemix Space            : Development(228a71ab-7409-4006-ac2f-2326a6a93f30)
CCS host/url             : https://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net
Registry host            : registry.ng.bluemix.net

Comment: Bluemix api host/url     : https://api.ng.bluemix.net
CCS API Version          : 0.0  
namespace                : ht123
Containers limit         : Unlimited
Containers usage         : 1
Containers running       : 1
CPU limit (cores)        : Unlimited
CPU usage (cores)        : 16
Memory limit(MB)         : 2048
Memory usage(MB)         : 1024
Floating IPs limit       : 2
Floating IPs allocated   : 1
Public IPs bound         : 1

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment "boot2docker has been deprecated" I assume you are using Docker 1.8.

This version of Docker is not supported by IBM Containers on Bluemix yet.

Please see documentation in link below saying Docker 1.6 or 1.7 is required:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_ov.html

I know IBM Containers team is working to add support for Docker 1.8 as well. Please keep an eye on documentation for updates in the future.

Comment: I still get the same error even after I've downgraded to docker 1.7.1 - screenshot - http://oi57.tinypic.com/n5hawp.jpg

Comment: Could you please let me know what do you have in .dockercfg file (should be in your home dir)? Also please paste the cf ic info output here.